# Change iframe src using javascript/jquery without setting protocol

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use Javascript to change the src of an iframe. However, the source I am trying to change it to is:

```
 //embed.expertfile.com/v1/expert/
```

However, when I attempt to do that using

```
document.getElementById('iframe2').src = url;
```

It will consistently add the site URL to it. So the end result would be:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask//embed.expertfile.com/v1/expert/
```

Is there anyway to prevent the current site URL from being added to the src?

Comment: Have you looked at the different components of [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location). You can prepend the current base url to the new location.

Comment: weird. it doesn't do that in Chrome when I try it. maybe try 3 slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Location object return from `window.location` to build up the url.

```
url = window.location;
console.log(url);
newurl = url.protocol +  url.host + '/embed.expertfile.com/v1/expert/';
console.log(newurl);
document.getElementById('iframe2').src = newurl;
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)